# angular 4 directives not working under svg tag

Tags: angular, svg

[image]

I am trying to use Angular 4 structural directives in an svg tag in html5. For ex ; `<svg <g *ngIf ></g></svg>` but it is error that `*ngIf` attribute is not allowed here can some tell what to do if i have to add conditions or click event in svg tag in angular 4 ?

Comment: If you get an error message, please add the exact and full error message to your questionl.

Comment: Does the `NgModule` that contains above component have `BrowserModule` or `CommonModule` in `imports: []`?

Comment: yes BrowserModule exists in app.module.ts

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in Plunker or http://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: error message = inspection element highlights unknown html tag attributes as invalid, and lets mark such attributes as custom to avoid highlighting them as invalid

Comment: That doesn't sound Angular related. Do you get an error if you build or run the code?

Comment: https://angular-wujlna.stackblitz.io

Comment: no i am not getting any error during ng build or ng serve

Comment: And do the directives (`*ngIf`) do what you expect?

Comment: The stackblitz link doesn't seem to work. You need to use the share feature to get a shareable link

Comment: i want to hide that <g> tag if the condition is not met!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wujlna?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The SVG doesn't show anything.

Comment: yes.. it was my editor problem! restarted it and it worked fine!

Comment: check this article here by Tero: https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html. Angular is not (yet) friendly with SVG as part of templates. But there are ways (based on your use case) how to get it work